# Drop blue point with custom coordinates Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, google-maps

I have a Map and i want to drop a blue point and circle on it. But not on my current location, but with customized latitude and longtude like i choose where the blue dot and circle to be droped.

So hiw to do it. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You may also want to consider your audience.  Are you certain you want to target Google Maps when the maps program changes in about a week or so.

Comment: Yes currently im targeting the google maps. And did implement it totally by dropping multiple pin annotations. But also i need to add the blue point to the last dropped pin.